# When is it appropriate to use variable arguments in an Objective-C method?

Tags: objective-c, c, variadic-functions

When is it appropriate to write a method with a variable number of arguments (like `NSString's +stringWithFormat:`)?

A brief search of variadic methods from Apple seems to include only two classes: when creating a data structure `(NSArray's +arrayWithObjects:, NSSet's +setWithObjects:)`, or when formatting a string `(NSString's +stringWithFormat:, NSPredicate's +predicateWithFormat:)`.

Apple's [documentation for variadic methods](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1405/_index.html) includes an example that is subtly different from the previously mentioned data structure methods, but still in the same camp.

Is it appropriate to use variadic methods in any other context? Does Apple?

Comment: This is too broad. Do you have a specific function for which you want to use variable arguments?

Comment: It highly depends on your needs. Do you have any method that would operate on variable number of arguments? If no, prefer using named parameters.

Answer (score 2):

> When is it appropriate to write a method with a variable number of arguments (like NSString's +stringWithFormat:)?

This method uses a `printf`-like attribute which checks the format string against the additional parameters. You should always add an attribute to your methods/functions when using a format string.

> A brief search of variadic methods from Apple seems to include only two classes: when creating a data structure (NSArray's +arrayWithObjects:, NSSet's +setWithObjects:), or when formatting a string (NSString's +stringWithFormat:, NSPredicate's +predicateWithFormat:).

This form uses a `nil` sentinel. It's actually a bit *relaxed* because an unexpected `nil` can silently truncate your parameters without error or warning. As an example, the (new-ish) Objective-C Literals do not use this form; they use implementations which also take count as a parameter, and it is an error to pass `nil` elements.

---

> Is it appropriate to use variadic methods in any other context?

It's used in many places in C, and there are also variadic macros. Generally, you should look for alternatives because variadics are a less safe API.

One place I will use them is if I need to wrap an API. In that case, I only forward the parameters to the API which takes the va_list.

You can find safer alternatives for almost every use case, especially since the introduction of blocks.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, Cocoa's uses of functions with variable number of arguments is limited to the two categories that you have mentioned. For example, `NSLog` and `NSAssert` can be considered functions from the second category, because it formats a string.

However, functions with variable number of arguments can be very useful when in other situations.

For example, you can define an API for evaluating expressions that looks like this:

```
NSNumber *res = [Evaluator evalExpression:@"%1 + %2 * %3", @10, @20, @5];
// returns @110
```

Another example could be an API for composing XML, like this:

```
MyXmlTree *tree = [MyXmlTree addElementWithTag:@"root" andChildren:
    [MyXmlTree elementWithTag:@"hello"]
,   [MyXmlTree elementWithTag:@"world"]
,   nil];
```

The second example is a more complex case of composing a data structure (i.e. composing a tree, rather than defining a linear structure).